# Linux: /var/log/syslog segfault message format? What does each parameter means?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

As per the Question title, What does each paramter stands for, in /var/log/syslog segfault messagae ?

For Example, I got the error message in /var/log/syslog file as :

```
Sep 17 03:57:23 localhost kernel: [   99.032748] IAccessRemoteSc[1413]: segfault at 11 ip 0804ca94 sp bfaf6d90 error 4 in IAccessRemoteScreen[8048000+a000]
```

where :

```
Sep 17 03:57:23 ==> TimeStamp

localhost kernel ==> Log Host

ip ==> Instruction Pointer

sp ==> Stack Pointer
```

What does other parameter stands for ?

```
[   99.032748] ==> ?

IAccessRemoteSc ==> ?

[1413] ==> ?

segfault ==>

11 ==>

0804ca94 ==>

bfaf6d90 ==>

error 4  ==>

IAccessRemoteScreen[8048000+a000] ==> ?

[8048000+a000] ==> ?
```

Is there any standard protocol for Syslog ?

I need a detail description for each paramter.

Can anyone suggest me any link or Manual to interpret details of above Message ?

Answer (score 1):

[   99.032748] ==> This seems to be a time (possibly, from the start of execution of this task. or total time consumed time this process )

IAccessRemoteSc ==> The offending function

[1413] ==> line number

segfault ==> segmentation fault, the immediate reason for the crash

11 ==> The address of text of offending code

0804ca94 ==> ip is instruction pointer. The cuurent executing instruction

bfaf6d90 ==> stack pointer. The pointer to the top of offending process's stack

error 4  ==> arch specific error code. Decoding is architectural specific as far as I know

IAccessRemoteScreen[8048000+a000] ==> the offending line in the function.

[8048000+a000] ==> The hex is the address of offending function and a000 is the offset to the offending line.

Comment: Thanks alot. Is there any link describing each in more details ? If you can also share the link with me, would be very helpful to me. I need to prepare a report describing each parameters for future use.

Comment: The linked question doesn't answer the what [1413] is and the above is confused. 1413 is the process id of the failed AccessRemoteSc process.